# Compiler warning when initializing member of template class to this

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

When initializing a member of class to `this` in C++, it works fine, until the class is a template class:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    A* next;

    A() : next(this) {}
};
```

Visual Studio gives the warning C26495: Always initialize a member variable. Why is this a problem when the class is a template class and how can I fix this? Or is this a problem with VS?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studios built-in compiler (v16.4 for Visual C++ v14.24). The given code already produces the warning.

Comment: same warning as seen by @walnut with a simple non-template class https://godbolt.org/z/atnBNU

Comment: So C26495 is not present if you remove the template-head? (I cannot test it myself) I would say in that case the warning is clearly inconsistent. The code is fine, `next` will always be initialized. So I don't know what problem it tries to communicate.

Comment: That's true, the warning disappears when I remove the template-head.

Comment: The only alternative I could think of (but that is still inconsistent with it only appearing in templates) is that the warning wants you to move the `this` initialization to a default member initializer (`A* next = this;`), which is what the C++ core guidelines [seem to recommend](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-in-class-initializer) and [as far as I can tell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c26495?view=vs-2019) your warning is a code quality warning based on these guidelines.

Comment: Warnings are not errors. passing `this` in initializer_list might be dangerous as the object is not fully initialized. Not a problem in your case though.